# Concatenate to form list scala

Tags: scala, list

I want to create a list of Test class.

```
 case class Person(name:String)

   case class Test (desc:String)

   val list =Seq(Person("abc"),Person("def"))
    val s = Option(list)
    private val elems = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Test]()
    val f =for{
      l<-s
    }yield {
      for{
        e <-l
      } yield elems+=tranform(e)

    }
    f.toSeq

    def tranform(p:Person):Test= {
    Test(desc = "Hello "+p.name)
    }
```

can anyone please help with the following

1. better way to avoid multiple `for`
2. I want to get List(Test("Hello abc"),Test("Hello def")) instead of using ArrayBuffer

Comment: You mention that your "actual use case returns option of list." How were we supposed to know that from your question? Please update your question to include use cases, source code of those use cases, and/or examples (either in code or by hand).

Comment: @coder25 `list.map(transform).flatten`. In all fairness, this is fairly basic collections API methods and your code shows you could benefit a lot from some tutorials on the Scala collections API, otherwise members here might be less able to help you properly in spite of their better intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're wrapping a `Seq` in an `Option`; `Seq` represents the no `Person`s case perfectly well.  Is there a difference between `None` and `Some(Seq.empty[Person])` in your application?

Assuming that you can get by without an `Option[Seq[Person]]`:

```
list.map(transform).toList
```

Comment: My actual use case returns a option of list.default for sequence is Nil